# Memory Management with paging

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

In the method of paging in the operating system memory management issues.
when we have `64 byte` for Pages ,why 6 bit needed?

```
 111111 ==> 63
 1000000 => 64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **6** bits you can represent  maximum **64** pages(**0-63**) in binary. As one single bit can take only two values **0** or **1**,so for **6** bits you have **2*2*2*2*2*2** or **2**<sup>**6**</sup> different permutations.Every permutation will identify a different page.